# How to find the value of theta 0 and theta 1?

Tags: machine-learning

I am new to ML, I am not sure on how to solve this problem

[image]

Could someone tell me how to solve this problem of finding values in a a step by step manner?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question, but an ML theory question.

Answer (score 1):

From **newcomer** view point you can actually just test:

> *h1*=0.5+0.5x
>
> *h2*=0+0.5x
>
> *h3*=0.5+0x
>
> *h4*=1+0.5x
>
> *h5*=1+x

Then which one of the ***hs***(1..5) gives exact observed values of **y**(0.5,1,2,0) for a given set of dependent variables **x**(1,2,4,0).

You can answer that by passing sample values of x in the above equation.
I hope i made it simple enough

Answer (score 0):

In general you would execute some non-iterative algorithmic approach (probably based on solving a system of linear equations) or some iterative approach like GD (Gradient Descent), but this is more simple here, as it's **already given that there is a perfect fit**.

Perfect fit means: **loss/error of zero**.

- Loss of zero implicates, that *sigma0* needs to be zero or else sample 4 (last one) induces a loss

  - Overall loss is the sum of sample-losses and each loss/component is nonnegative -> we can't tolerate a loss here
- When sigma0 is fixed, sample 4 has an infinite amount of solutions producing no loss
- But sample 1 shows that it has to be 0.5 to induce no loss
- Check the others, it's fitting perfectly

One assumption i made:

- Gradient-descent will converge to the optimal solution (which is not always true, even for convex-optimization problems; it's depending learning-rates; one might use line-searches to proof convergence based on some assumptions about the problem; but all that is irrelevant here)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the cache It's one of most easy problems in machine learning.

Just see that we have to create a linear regression model to fit the following data:-

**STEP 1:UNDERSTANDING THE PROBLEM**

*And as mentioned at the last of question it should completely fit the data.*

We have to find `theta0` and `theta1` in such a way such that given value of x `Htheta(x)` will give the correct value of y.

**STEP 2:FINDING THETA1**

In these m examples take any 2 random examples

```
Htheta(x2)-Htheta(x1) = theta1*(x2)-theta1*(x1)
-----Subtracting those 2 variables(eliminating theta0)


hteta(x2) = y2
(y corresponding to that x in the data as the parameters exactly fit the data provided )


(y2-y1)/(x2-x1) = theta1
----taking common and then dividing by(x2-x1) on both sides of equation
```

From this:

```
theta1 = 0.5
```

**STEP3 :CALCULATING THETA0**

Take any random example and put the values of `theta1`, `y` and `x` in this equation

```
y = theta1*x + theta0
```

`theta0` will come out to be 0

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to view these points by plotting a graph with x,y values. Since it's a straight line, calculate `tan(theta)` using normal trigonometry, which in this case is `y/x`(Since it's mentioned they fit perfectly!!). eg:- 
`tan(theta1) = 0.5/1 or 1/2`

Calculate `arctan(1/2) // Approx 0.5`

Note:- This is not a scalable approach but just some maths fun! Sorry.